# Why do torch.add and torch.einsum return different results?

Tags: python, pytorch, numpy-einsum

```py
t=m+n
x=torch.einsum('xyzw,xyzw->xyzw',m,n)
```

When I try this code, I get `x` that's different from `t`, which is surprising. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`einsum` is actually a product of its inputs. It's only a sum over the indexes that do not occur in the output.

So,

```
x=torch.einsum('xyzw,xyzw->xyzw',m,n)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
x = m * n
```